# Where do Sam & Dean get money from?

Tags: plot-explanation, supernatural

I was watching Supernatural yesterday, and Dean bribed a motel clerk to get some info about vampires. Then it hit me, where do they get money?

I am aware that Dean was a construction worker in the 6th season. But given how they are always on the road, it doesn't explain how they get along.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By credit card scam or stolen credit cards (mentioned in first season) and by hustles pool and poker games.

Answer (score -3):

I was wondering about that myself. I've heard the stolen credit card part too. Let's just say that there is a very rich man who shall course remain unknown, has a vested interest in their cause. That man leaves money all over the USA for them to use. This rich man is someone their Dad saved years ago. or else we will have to actually see Dean playing pool more often like every week.

Comment: Doesn't sound too likely. Do you have any references or other inormation to support this theory?

Comment: After 10 seasons, I think that this source of money would get hit by various creatures. You just don't go 10 seasons without exploiting every personal relation the characters have. So, IMO, the above is just a fan fiction.